# How to convert excel stringified JSON coming from Angular 7 to List of Entity object and save it to database?

Tags: java, json, angular, spring

I have excel JSON stringified from angular 7  in the following pattern

`[{"Employee ID":"1234","Employee Name":"ABC","Designation":"Manager","Salary":"50000"}...]`

I'm using `List<<object>>` of `object` in `controller` class to fetch JSON from UI

## Controller.java

```
@PostMapping("/fetchExcelJson")

public void fetchExcelJson(@RequestBody List<<Object>> jsonData) {

employeeService.fetchJsonData(jsonDaata);

}
```

## ServiceImpl.java

```
@Override

public void fetchJsonData(List<<Object>> jsonData) {

Iterator<Object> iterator = jsonData.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()) {

Object obj = iterator.next();

System.out.println(obj);

}

}
```

When I'm sending JSON from UI to backend I'm getting this response in backend

`{"Employee ID":"1234","Employee Name":"ABC","Designation":"Manager","Salary":"50000"}`...

I need to convert this JSON from backend in this format

`{"employeeId":"1234","employeeName":"ABC","designation":"Manager","salary":"50000"}`...

If I use Entity object I'm getting JSON parse error. I just need to iterate this list of JSON coming from UI only in backend format.

Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: is it possible to alter the code coming from the front end? seems a little like crossing the river to get water that you want to rewrite it completely in the backend

Answer (score 0):

Sample JSON

```
    {
     "data": [
      {
         "employeeId": "Dummy",
         "employeeName": "Dummy",
         "designation": "Dummy",
         "salary": 50000
      },
      {
         "employeeId": "Dummy1",
         "employeeName": "Dummy1",
         "designation": "Dummy1",
         "salary": 5000
      }
   ]
  }
```

Sample Java POJO

```
public class Employee {

private String employeeId;
private String employeeName;
private String designation;
private Double salary;

//Getters and Setters


}
```

Controller.java

```
@PostMapping("/fetchExcelJson")

public void fetchExcelJson(@RequestBody List<Employee> data) {

  employeeService.fetchJsonData(jsonDaata);

}
```